# How can I set my unordered list to be in the middle not in-line (see image)?

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve the following (see image)? I want my list elements to be in the middle, so far what I have attempted is aligned on the same line as the logo (or H1).

I tried applying a margin top to the li but that didn't work at all. I'd appreciate if someone can guide me on where I've gone wrong.

Thanks

[image]

My attempt:

```html
<html>
<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"></header>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="logo">LogoHere</h1>

        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Who we are</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Get in touch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    font-size: 54px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
    color: #444444;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 55%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

.nav-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}

li a:hover {color: #444444;}  /* mouse over link */

li a:active {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}  /* selected link */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

```
.setMiddle
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

It set element middle in box (div). You have done several margin, padding. So first remove these and then apply `.setMiddle`. Either you need to apply this with `h1` or `ul`.

Edit: Apply .setMiddle to `h1` and `li` it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/6uuXC/1/

Comment: by removing the padding-top on the logo it has changed the positioning to all the way top, this is not what I wanted, although setting it to middle has worked. Is there a way of not removing the padding? I want some space above the .logo div

Comment: oh nvm, it worked. I applied the padding to the first div which s wrapping all this.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using the CSS `line-height` property effectively. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWj4Y/) that shows how you can accomplish this.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  line-height: 100px;
}
header span {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer but that didn't work with my code. I tried putting the line-height nav-menu li but nothing happened. Can you show me an example of how it would work with list, please?